# VB stringbuilder Contains

Tags: .net, vb.net, stringbuilder

I have a stringbuilder in VB

I like to check to see if it contains a value if so I like to do something:

```
If strMsg.Contains("<table>") Then
  ' strMsg = strMsg + "<br/><br/><br/>"
  strMsg.Append("<br/><br/><br/>")
End If
```

I tried the above but said contains is not a member of System.Text.StringBuilder.

What can I use in place of Contains

Comment: how is the stringbuilder being built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains()` is not among [Stringbuilder's methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder_methods). That said, you have a couple options...

1.: Test your values on the way in and maintain a boolean flag for your *append `<br>` tags* state.

2.: Perform `ToString()` and call `Contains()` from the result:

```
if strMsg.ToString().Contains("<table>") then '...
```

3.: Implement `IndexOf()` and/or `Contains()` yourself:

```
Module StringBuilderExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IndexOf(ByVal sb As StringBuilder, ByVal value As String) As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To sb.Length - value.Length - 1

            For y As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1

                If value(y) <> sb(i + y) Then

                    Exit For

                ElseIf y = value.Length - 1 Then

                    Return i

                End If

            Next

        Next

        Return -1

    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Contains(ByVal sb As StringBuilder, ByVal value As String) As Boolean

        Return sb.IndexOf(value) > -1

    End Function

End Module
```

**Disclaimer**: This hasn't been tested for performance... and Michael Haren's comment was directed at the `ToString()` option.

Comment: This will work, but the other answer would perform a lot better

Answer (score 4):

I would check your inputs into the `StringBuilder` for this condition.

```
Dim hasTable As Boolean = False

' Check inputs, set hasTable to True if needed

If hasTable Then
    strMsg.Append("<br/><br/><br/>")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given suggesting to monitor the input is the best option, but if you need to do anything that needs to access `StringBuilder.ToString` *prior to the final* `ToString` -- and that is the alternative in this case -- use `sb.ToString(0, sb.Length)` so a new `String` is definitely created and the one being built can continue to be (efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

```
If strMsg.ToString().Contains("<table>") Then
    strMsg.Append("<br /><br /><br />")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Regular Expressions too. They allow you to search a large amount of text and manipulate it. This [site](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) has a great program to experiment with them.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) is a good tutorial on them too.